# Applescript returning error when storing strings in a list

Tags: macos, applescript

I wrote a simple script that finds out how many active processes are running on the machine right now, and outputs the paths of each one into an array as a string.

Here's my code (it really has no legitimate function, I'm just trying to try different things to see how applescript works):

```
tell application "System Events"
  set activeProcess to number of process
  set paths to {0}
  repeat with n from 1 to activeProcess
    set last item of list paths to (file of process n as string)
  end repeat
end tell
```

And here's the error applescript editor returns when I hit run:

```
System Events got an error: Can’t set list {0} to "Macintosh HD:System:Library:CoreServices:loginwindow.app:".
```

What am I don't wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "System Events" to set myprocess to files of processes
```

or

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed
tell application "System Events" to set myprocess to paragraphs of (files of processes as text)
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
```

You can build a list from a repeat loop like this:

```
set paths to {}
tell application "System Events"
    set activeProcess to processes
    repeat with n from 1 to count activeProcess
        set end of paths to (file of item n of activeProcess as text)
    end repeat
end tell
```

or like this:

```
set paths to {}
tell application "System Events"
    set activeProcess to processes
    repeat with aProcess in activeProcess
        set end of paths to (file of aProcess as text)
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Wow, that's not very intuitive; and Applescript is supposed to be amateur friendly :( Thanks for your help!